# php - json_decode return json data

Tags: php, json, function, decode

I would like to `json_decode()` all files from a directory and use their data.

```php
<?php

$dir = "../mynotes";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
      if($file != ".." && $file != "..." && $file != "."){
        $fileContent = @file_get_contents("../mynotes/".$file);
        $mynote = json_decode($fileContent,true);
        print_r($mynote);
      }
  }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}

?>
```

When I want to `echo $mynote['id];`, It returns me:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'id'

Could you help me ?

---

EDIT:
I got it. [Solution](http://pastebin.com/AG9sqFsw)

Comment: var_dump **$mynote** to see what is in there.

Comment: It returns JSON data: string(148) "{"id":"55cb73c66213b","title":"Slt cv frere","category":"Discussion","content":"Yo cv ? Ue. Ok.","writer_name":"Jason","dateOfWriting":"2015-08-12"}"

Comment: This is **json** and not an array where you could call the index, that is not possible.

Comment: Then what json_decode() do ? I given json and it returns json ?

Comment: @JasonVanMalder It is a matter of simple google search. [Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Send the optional `TRUE` as the second parameter to it if you want an array instead of an object.